# Resume animation after return from background state in Swift with UIViewRepresentable?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my SwiftUI application, I have to use the makeUIView function to create and animate a "sonar" view for some reasons in a UIViewRepresentable. I just have a problem with an animation: when I move the app to the background and return to it, the animation stops and doesn't automatically restart. I've searched the web for several solutions, but I'm not sure how to fix this problem in my code.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct SonarView: View {
  
  var width: CGFloat
  var height: CGFloat
  
  struct TargetView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var width: CGFloat
    var height: CGFloat            
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
      
      // Circle
      let circle = UIView()
      circle.frame = CGRect.init(x: 2, y: 2, width: width, height: height)
      circle.layer.cornerRadius = width / 2
      circle.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "PrimaryLight")?.cgColor
      circle.layer.borderWidth = 2
      circle.layer.borderColor = UIColor(named: "PrimaryDark")?.cgColor            
           
      return circle
    }
  
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.75, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
            uiView.subviews[0].transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
        }, completion: nil)
    }     
                
  }  
  
  var body: some View {
    TargetView(     
      width: self.width,
      height: self.height,
    )
  }
}
```

In SwiftUI part, I implement the sonar view simply like this:

```
...
SonarView(width: geometry.size.height, height: geometry.size.height)
  .frame(width: geometry.size.height, height: geometry.size.height)
  .opacity(self.targetOpacity ? 1.0 : .zero)
  .onAppear {
     self.isNotNavigatingAnimationDelay = true
     withAnimation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.5).delay(0.5)) {
       self.targetOpacity = true
    }
  }
  .onDisappear {
    self.targetOpacity = false
    self.targetOffset = .zero
  }
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CABasicAnimation`.

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        basicAnimation.toValue = 1.2
        basicAnimation.duration = 1.75
        basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        basicAnimation.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        basicAnimation.autoreverses = true
        uiView.subviews[0].layer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "transformanimation")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! It work great in makeUIView function